# How to handle the 4 sides of rect object in case of intersectsWith another one?

Tags: c#, wpf, rect

I have to 2 rect objects. One of that cannot move, another one is moving. I would like handle that when its intersectsWith the first one of each side. Something like:

```
if (rect1.IntersectsWith(rect2))
 {
     if (rect1.Top == rect2.Bottom)
     {
      ...
     }
     else if (rect1.Bottom == rect2.Top)
     {
      ...
     }
     else if (rect1.Left == rect2.Right)
     {
      ...
     }
     else if (rect1.Right == rect2.Left)
     {
      ...
     }
 }
```

This gives me not an accurate results. Any idea?

Comment: Well, first of all, "overlapping" does not necessarily mean that edges are perfectly touching each other... checking if one edge == another is probably not the correct logic. However, I don't really understand the rest of your question. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just trying some simple things. For example: if rect2 hit the top side of rect1 then move rect1 some pixel to bottom direction, and the same with the other sides.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you already have a way to determine whether the two rectangles are colliding, which is good because it makes your job easier. All you have to do now is to determine which side the collision happened on, and then to act accordingly.

If that's the case, then you're already on the right track. However, your logic on the checks is a bit faulty. You're checking if one edge *is exactly on top of* another edge. In most applications, this is actually pretty rare. What you should be checking is if there is any overlap, which you need the `<=` and `>=` comparators for.

```
if (rect1.IntersectsWith(rect2))
{
    // assumes that positive Y signifies downward direction
    if (rect1.Top <= rect2.Bottom)
    {
        ...
    }
    else if (rect1.Bottom >= rect2.Top)
    {
        ...
    }
    else if (rect1.Left <= rect2.Right)
    {
        ...
    }
    else if (rect1.Right >= rect2.Left)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately its stil gives me wrong results. Exmaple when it hits the right side, the rect1.Top is can be smaller than rect2.Bottom and handling that like hitting the top of rect1. Any idea? There is something wrong with the conditions.

Comment: You are using `else-if`, which means only one of these conditions will trigger when the rectangles intersect. Remove the `else` if you want to check each of them at once.